# Plane Circling an airport.

Tags: trigonometry, circles

- A plane is going in circle around an airport the plane takes $3$ minutes to complete one round.
- The angle of elevation of the plane from point $p$ on the ground at time $t$ seconds is equal to that at time $(t+30)$ seconds.
- At time $(t+x)$ seconds the plane flies vertically above the point $p$.

What is $x$ equal to?

I have tried using basic trig, but that doesn't helps, may be there is some use of circle chord or something.

Comment: I have inserted some full stops and other punctuation to separate sentences, but you might want to check it still says what you intended.  You might also consider whether there is enough information to answer the question

Comment: Yes, it's still correct. :)

Comment: @Henry , You have any clue on how to solve it?

Comment: Not really, though a symmetry idea might suggest something like $x=15$ or $105$ seconds

Comment: @Henry, that's super correct, 105 is the answer, what did you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to proceed:

- Assume, at time t, the plane is at the point A on the circle.
- After 30s, the plane arrives at the point B. Because it takes 180s to fly the full 360° circle, the arc A to B spans 60°.
- Let C be the point on the circle when the plane is directly above p. Then, AC = BC due to the same elevation angles. So, ∆ABC is an isosceles triangle inscribing the circle.
- Thus, from A to C, the plane flies an arc of 150°+60° = 210°, or 7/12 (210°/360°) of a full circle.
- Therefore, $x$ = (7/12)$\cdot$180s = 105s.

The other possibility is that the point C lies midway along the path AB, the 60°-arc. In this case, the arc AC spans 60°/2 = 30° and $x$ = 15s.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!, I'll try draw a diagram for this and post it for others.

Comment: @UbdusSamad - You’re welcome. Indeed, a diagram would help visualize the relationship of all the segments and angles in the question.

Comment: Hi @Quanto , Do you think this diagram is descriptive & accurate enough?

Comment: It is good; thanks. I reproduced it with some refinements.